# Ho to set status code 400 in response object

Tags: java, api, error-handling, response

I am using Response object from javax.ws.rs-api and even though I can set status like Response.status(Response.status.BAD_REQUEST).build() , the response code returned is always 200 with a response body that contains statusInfo parameter which says BAD_REQUEST. 
Is there a way to set response code as 400 based on some validations of input on server side?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just setting response status, throw error from service layer and let it propagate to the Controller.
In the controller you could have something like

```
@Controller
public class MyService {
    @RequestMapping(value = "your api url path", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/
    public Response jsonAccounts(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Bad request received").build();
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MyBadException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason = "Bad request Request Exception")
    public void unexpectedError(HttpServletRequest request, Exception 
        log.debug("return HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, unexpectedError due to Exception", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if OP is using Spring framework. The Answer will only work for Spring based application.

Comment: In your example is this the process flow : request handled by jsonAccounts() -> service call is made ->service throws an error -> error is handled by unexpectedError() of controller ?

Comment: Yes @ShashankSinghal, but as Prashant metioned will work only with Spring

Comment: Is there a way for jsonAccounts() method of controller to set the response status without using @ResponseStatus tag ?

Comment: @RahulAgrawal thanks for the update but when i tested the same with swagger/postman the response status was always 200 (hence my original question) but the response body contains statusInfo parameter which says BAD_REQUEST.

Comment: Hello, I have the same exact problem, were you able to find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This  works for  me, i tested.

```
 @GET
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getTestResult() {
    logger.info("Requested Test Service");
    try {
        Object result = "";[enter image description here][1]
      return  Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
              .entity(result).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.ok("error", e.getMessage()).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I tested using swagger/postman I got response status as 200